# Динамическое создание сервисов в symfony 5

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, symfony5

Столкнулся в симфони с такой проблемой.

Если мне нужен какой-либо сервис то я делаю так

```
class Controller 
{
    /**
     * @var MyService
     */
    private $service;

    public function __construct(MyService $service)
    {
        $this->service = $service;
    }
}
```

или так

```
class Controller2 
{

    public function someAction(MyService2 $service)
    {
    }
}
```

Но что если мне нужно неограниченное количество сервисов в зависимости от условий?

К примеру,

```
class Router {
    public function match($params)
    {
        $someServiceClass = $this->getServiceByParams($params);
        $someService = new $someServiceClass();
        return $someService;
    }
}
```

но в том же $someServiceClass в конструкторе могут быть любые сервисы, т.е. я не могу просто взять и создать

```
new $someServiceClass();
```

Например в Magento 2 есть такая штука, как ObjectManager, когда я могу сделать просто

```
$objectManager->get(MyClass::class)
```

И он вернет инстанс класса со всеми заинжекченными сервисами в конструктор.

Есть ли в симфони такая возможность?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можете воспользоваться [Service Subscriber](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_subscribers_locators.html#defining-a-service-subscriber)

```
class Router implements ServiceSubscriberInterface {

    private $locator;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $locator)
    {
        $this->locator = $locator;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedServices()
    {
        // список ваших возможных сервисов
        return [
            'foo' => FooService::class,
            'bar' => BarService::class,
        ];
    }

   // $params = 'foo' или 'bar'
    public function match($params)
    {
        if($this->locator->has($params) {
            $someService = $this->locator->get($params);
            return $someService;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: То есть в любом случае изначально сервисы нужно регистрировать? Не получится, как с классами контроллеров - просто создать класс, который зарегистрирован по умолчанию.

Comment: если используется `autowire: true` то сервисы уже зарегистрированы

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете воспользоваться контейнером симфони `$this->container->get(Service::class)`, вот только доставать сервисы через контейнер по их названию возможно только если сервис является публичным. Вы можете сделать нужный сервис публичным таким отбразом:

Файл `services.yaml`

```
App\Service\Ваш сервис:
    public: true
```

Comment: таким образом, каждый сервис нужно будет указывать в `services.yaml`, а этого хотелось бы избежать, т.к. их может быть неограниченное количество и это неудобно.

Comment: @NikolasSumrak вы можете указать в `services.yaml` параметр `services:/_defaults:/public: true` и тогда у вас ВСЕ сервисы станут публичными и можете их вызывать через `container->get` не прописывая каждый, но это не считается хорошей практикой _"Как бы легко это ни показалось, непосредственное использование контейнера не считается хорошей практикой, поскольку оно скрывает зависимости ваших классов, связывая их с внешней конфигурацией, что затрудняет тестирование, проверку и т. д."_ и было убрано с версии 3.4. Хозяин-барин